# Veins in Plant Leaves (terminology)

Tags: botany, terminology

Why do we call the vascular bundles in plant leaves "veins"? I think its probably because the xylem and pholem serve circulatory function analogous to the human body's circulatory system with arteries and veins. But why don't we call the vascular bundles arteries instead or veins?

In the human body, we call a blood vessel "vein" when it travels blood to the heart and an "artery" when a blood vessel travels blood away from the heart. Is there a similar reason or significance as to why we call vascular bundles "veins" instead of "arteries"?

Comment: It's just a colloquial term and not a well thought of/standardized term. So there is nothing much to reason here.

Comment: I think this is a valid question with valid historical (not simply colloquial) usage and I think that potential answers could definitely be based on more than just an opinion. I disagree with both close voters and vote to keep open.